# Multiple buttons with the same #id to do the same function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, bpopup

JS beginner, sorry

How can could I make it so that every button that has the id "#popit" to open the same popup box?

I'm using [bPopup](http://dinbror.dk/blog/bPopup/)

With this code there is only one button on the site which does open the popup

```
;(function($) {
    $(function() {
        $('#my-button').bind('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#element_to_pop_up').bPopup();
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yg5so25s/ - there are 3 buttons with the same id, but only the first one opens the popup box, anyway I could make it so that every single button to open the same popupbox?

Comment: You should use classes when you want to identify multiple elements. id should be unique

Comment: By definition, an id *must be* **unique**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`id` must be unique, you need to use class instead:

```
<button class="my-button">POP IT UP</button>
```

then you can use `.` to target elements by class name:

```
;(function($) {
    $(function() {
        $('.my-button').bind('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#element_to_pop_up').bPopup();
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yg5so25s/2/)**

Comment: So simple and yet dumb me couldn't figure it out myself! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 4):

use common class for all buttons

```
$('.commonClass').bind('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#element_to_pop_up').bPopup();
        });
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yg5so25s/3/)**